# ¿Como puedo hacer paso de datos entre dialogos?

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy haciendo un ERP que necesita paso de datos entre diálogos y he tenido muchos problemas, lo que quiero hacer exactamente es pasar la informacion de añadirArticulo (exactamente el nombre de articulo) y aplicarlo a mi variable nombreArt en agregar.

Intenté en varias ocasiones crear una variable con el get pero retorna null por obvias razones y da también muchos problemas al querer implementar una base de datos.

```
    agregar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Dialog dialogo = new Dialog(Alcrud.this);
            dialogo.setTitle("Nuevo Registro");
            dialogo.setCancelable(true);
            dialogo.setContentView(R.layout.aldialogo);
            dialogo.show();

            EditText nombreArt= (EditText)dialogo.findViewById(R.id.nomArt);
            EditText nombre= (EditText)dialogo.findViewById(R.id.nomAl);
            Button guardar=(Button)dialogo.findViewById(R.id.botonagregarAl);
            Button cancelar=(Button)dialogo.findViewById(R.id.botoncancelAl);
            guardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try{
                        almacen=new Almacen(nombre.getText().toString());
                        dao.insertarAl(almacen);
                        listaAl=dao.verTodosAl();
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        dialogo.dismiss();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                }
            });
            cancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialogo.dismiss();
                }
           });
        }
    });
}
public void añadirArticulo(View view) {
    Dialog dialogo = new Dialog(Alcrud.this);
    dialogo.setTitle("Nuevo Registro");
    dialogo.setCancelable(true);
    dialogo.setContentView(R.layout.artdialogo);
    dialogo.show();

    EditText nombre= (EditText)dialogo.findViewById(R.id.nomArt);
    EditText existencias= (EditText)dialogo.findViewById(R.id.existArt);
    EditText precio= (EditText)dialogo.findViewById(R.id.preArt);
    Button guardar=(Button)dialogo.findViewById(R.id.botonagregarArt);
    Button cancelar=(Button)dialogo.findViewById(R.id.botoncancelArt);

    guardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try{
                articulo=new Articulo(nombre.getText().toString(),
                        existencias.getText().toString(),
                        precio.getText().toString());
                dao.insertarArt(articulo);
                listaArt=dao.verTodosArt();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                dialogo.dismiss();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El nombre que usas en `añadirArticulo()` lo obtienes desde el `EditText` con la variable `nombre`:

```
nombre.getText().toString()
```

si deseas obtener este valor y aplicarlo a mi variable `nombreArt` en `agregar()`, simplemente agrega el valor a esta variable:

```
nombreArt =  nombre.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, pero tendría que castear el EditText a String, además si añado directamente nombreArt.getText().toString() en agregar (en el trycatch) me sale nullpointer porque no me guarda la variable cuando añado artículo. @Elenasys

Comment: ¿Podría pasarte mi proyecto para que lo veas todo (por privado)?